# ls() returns a.1, a.10, a.2, ... instead of a.1, a.2, a.3,..., a.10

Tags: r

Let say that I have 10 objects in R environment named a.1, a.2, ..., a.10

```
for(i in 1:10) assign(paste("a", i, sep="."), iris)
rm(i)
```

If I were to call `ls()`, it would return as:

```
 "a.1"  "a.10" "a.2"  "a.3"  "a.4"  "a.5"  "a.6"  "a.7"  "a.8"  "a.9"
```

instead of

```
"a.1"  "a.2"  "a.3"  "a.4"  "a.5"  "a.6"  "a.7"  "a.8"  "a.9" "a.10"
```

May I know if there's any method to force `ls()` to return in the latter sequence, instead of the former?

Comment: look at `?mixedsort()` from `gtools` package.

Comment: Nope. `mixedsort` doesn't work... It will work if the character and numerals are not separated by `[.]`

Comment: Your actual problem is that you "have 10 objects in R environment named a.1, a.2, ..., a.10". Those probably should be in a list. Then this would be a non-issue.

Comment: @Roland Thanks and I completely agree with your point. However, I did made a mistake of creating the bizarrely named objects in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802597/how-to-combine-vectors-in-r/37803178?noredirect=1#comment63119668_37803178 Was just wondering if there's a way to call for natural order...

Comment: `x <- ls(); x[order(as.numeric(gsub("[^[:digit:]]*", "", x)))]`

Comment: And please don't write answers promoting bad practices.

Comment: Thanks for the help. And yes, I'd screwed up big time...